# How to save data from an Angular 2 form (using angular material) in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-material2, firebase-hosting

I have created a form in Angular 2 using angular material. Below is the working code:

```
<form>
    <md-input-container>
        <md-placeholder>
            <md-icon>face</md-icon> Name
        </md-placeholder>
        <input mdInput name="name" [(ngModel)]="name"  required>
        <md-error>This field is required</md-error>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container>
        <md-placeholder>
            <md-icon>email</md-icon> Email
        </md-placeholder>
        <input mdInput name="email" [(ngModel)]="email"  required>
        <md-error>This field is required</md-error>
    </md-input-container>

    <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

I'm going to host this webpage in Firebase hosting (https://firebase.google.com). Now I want to know how can I save these two user inputs (name and email) in database when user will click submit button. I'm facing 1 more issue if I try a code like this:

```
<form action="some_url" method="post" #form>
  ....
  ....
<button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)="form.submit()">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

It is submitting the form without doing any validation like if form fields are empty then also it is submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your Component code looks like, you need to add validations in the component class.

You can read more about [Form validations in angular here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html).

Once you have valid data you can easily use [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) for saving data.

```
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

...
constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

submit(){
   someOBj = {name: <value>,email: <value>}

   // If list
   this.af.database.list(<url>).push(someOBj);
   // If object
   this.af.database.object(<url>).set(someOBj);
}
...
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I have put 'required' in <input> tag. That's the only validation. In my starting code if I click on submit without any input , it shows the the error messages, so no need to add validation in component class.

Comment: yes, it will show error messages, but it will not stop the submit action, for that you need to handle the errors and handle it so that submit action is not performed, you may disable the button until all errors are not resolved. Check the link which i have shared it lists all possible scenarios.